# Order displayed results by id in php

Tags: php, mysql

A webpage displays results from a table in a MySQL database and then order's them using;

```
$quey1="select * FROM tbname ORDER BY id DESC";
```

"id" uses auto_increment. I have deleted some of the id's. <- Is this why the ordering isn't working?

How can I fix this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't think this is the reason. Is this the only code you have (aside some `mysql_query()` or something)?

Maybe you could provide some additional code.

Comment: define "ordering isn't working". nobody knows what results you expect and what results you get

Answer (score 1):

MySQL orders results regardless of gaps in an auto-incremented column. Your query is correct, and should order results by `id` in descending order. It's possible that any post-processing you may be doing with the data is messing with the order it is presented.

Comment: how it can be regarding gaps anyway?!

Comment: Well. I don't know. The script I have is also counting the number of rows. That could be it. I will try. 

//EDIT:
That was it.